# PHP Array Blocklist

Tags: php, arrays, blacklist

I've created this code to cycle through the folders in the current directory and echo out a link to the folder, it all works fine. How would I go about using the `$blacklist` array as an array to hold the directory names of directories I **dont** want to show?

```
$blacklist = array('dropdown');

$results = array();
$dir = opendir("./");

while($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $results[] = $file;
    }
}

closedir($dir);

foreach($results as $file) {
    if($blocked != true) {
        $fileUrl = $file;
        $fileExplodedName = explode("_", $file);
        $fileName = "";
        $fileNameCount = count($fileExplodedName);

        echo "<a href='".$fileUrl."'>";

        $i = 1;

        foreach($fileExplodedName as $name) {
            $fileName .= $name." ";
        }       

        echo trim($fileName);
        echo "</a><br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `array_filter` together with `in_array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [in_array](http://php.net/in_array) for this.

```
$blocked = in_array($file, $blacklist);
```

Note that this is rather expensive. The runtime complexity of in_array is O(n) so don't make a large blacklist. This is actually faster, but with more "clumsy" code:

```
$blacklist = array('dropdown' => true);
/* ... */
$blocked = isset($blacklist[$file]);
```

The runtime complexity of the block check is then reduced to O(1) since the array (hashmap) is constant time on key lookup.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! How silly of me to forget about in_array!

Comment: An easy way to convert your array blacklist to the form suggested by Emil is to use array_fill_keys: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php. I.e: `$blackListKeyForm = array_fill_keys($blacklist, true);`

Answer (score 4):

[`array_diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) is the best tool for this job -- it's the shortest to write, very clear to read, and I would expect also the fastest.

```
$filesToShow = array_diff($results, $blacklist);
foreach($filesToShow as $file) {
    // display the file
}
```

Comment: I have not checked the PHP source code, but I suppose the runtime complexity of array_diff is in the neighbourhood of O(n) in the size of the first parameter.  If that's the case, with your solution the $results array will have to be looped over twice instead of once. It's hard to tell however - maybe the isset-check from my second solution is so slow that array_diff wins - the only way to know is probably to try them both.

Comment: @EmilVikström: I expect it to be fastest because it's in essence compiled C code and doesn't have to go through the Zend engine for each statement. Also, for small values of `n` (and they will certainly be small in this case) the running time will be dominated by factors other than the theoretical algorithmic complexity.